# Are too many template tags in Django bad?

Tags: python, html, django

I'm working on a django project and i'm going to have a couple of modals appear in several views, so i'm thinking of creating a file called `template_tags.py` so instead of:

```
<div class='modal fade' id='myModal'>
...
</div>
```

On the view, i create the modal on `template_tags.py` and just use

```
{{myModal}}
```

Is that a bad idea server-wise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, its not a bad idea. But [*there has to be a better way*](https://youtu.be/wf-BqAjZb8M?t=23m20s)!

Why not write the modal in a HTML file, say `my_modal.html` and then just [`include`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#include) it in other templates like this:

```
<!-- another_template.html -->

{% include 'path/to/my_modal.html' %}
```

If you want to pass arguments inside `my_modal.html` do it like this:

```
<!-- another_template.html -->

{% include 'path/to/my_modal.html' with var1='abc' var2='cba' %}
```

Comment: Thanks! I had figured my idea wasn't the most efficient way, it was the closer thing i came up with to how i used to do it in PHP.

Comment: Glad I could help. Best regards!